# How to dynamically add language to URL in React using i18next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I need to add language to url i.e. this is how the URL looks now http://localhost:3000/, http://localhost:3000/news, but it needs to be like this http://localhost:3000/en, http://localhost:3000/en/news.

At the same time, when someone sends a link to this site, the language must be taken from the link. Here is my code. Languages work, change on click.

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

i18n
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(HttpApi)
    .init({
        supportedLngs: ['ru', 'en', 'kk'],
        fallbackLng: "en",
        detection: {
            order: ["cookie", "localStorage", "htmlTag", "path", "subdomain"],
            caches: ["cookie"],
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false
        }
    });

  export default i18n;
```

But how to add to URL automatically? Are there ready-made solutions for this?

Comment: Use the JavaScript `history` `pushState` or `replaceState` methods.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to get the parameters from the URL with the help of `useParams()` hook available in react-routerv5.

While defining the url, you need to add a `param value` like this:
`<Route path="/:lang/news" component={News} />` where `:lang` is the value that you will receive from the URL.

Say someone enters `yourapp.com/en/news`, here parameter lang will be loaded with the value `en`. So, now to extract this value, you can use `import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";` and then inside the function component (as hooks work inside functional components only): `const { lang } = useParams();` where lang is your parameter.
After this, you could use `i18n` to translate as per the received language.

Edit:
@Gavara.Suneel in the comments has suggested an important change, once we identify the language from the URL, we should use `i18n.changeLanguage(lang)` to set the new language as default

Comment: How do you change the language in the url? For example, if I click on another language in the menu, it should also change in the URL, how can I do this?

Comment: You could use the `history` object with the help of `useHistory` hook and update the URL by pushing a new address with the desired language. Import this from `react-router-dom` and then `const history = useHistory()`. When you get the value for the new language, just do ```history.push(`/${newLang}/news`)``` or `history.replace`

Comment: You will also need to use the `useEffect` hook to update your language when the `lang` parameter updates.

Comment: `newLang` is the variable you are using to store the language selected in menu that you wish to load. Also, accept the answer if it helps, thanks!

Comment: I think this solution works fine @HasanRiza. I would suggest a small change/update on your solution. Once we get the language using **const { lang } = useParams();** then we have to set this language to i18n like **i18n.changeLanguage(lang)** so that the default language that we set during initialization would be overridden.